# Network Error at XMLHttpRequest.s.onerror (oidc-client.min.js:3) with angular 7 and Asp.net core 2.2

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

Trying to use the identity server 4 for authentication in asp.net core 2.2 with angular 7 application.

**oidc-login-redirect.html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/oidc-client/1.5.4/oidc-client.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var config = {
    userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })
  };
  var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);
  mgr.signinRedirectCallback().then(() => {
        window.history.replaceState({},
            window.document.title,
            window.location.origin);
        window.location = "/";
    }, error => {
        console.error(error);
    });

</script>
```

**Angular Auth Service code**

```
export class AuthServiceJwt implements CanActivate {
    _userManager: UserManager;
    _user: User;
    constructor(public router: Router) {
        //Log.logger = console;
        var config = {
            authority: environment.authority,
            client_id: environment.client_id,
            redirect_uri: `${environment.client_root_url}assets/oidc-login-redirect.html`,
            scope: environment.scope,
            response_type: environment.response_type,
            post_logout_redirect_uri: `${environment.client_root_url}?postLogout=true`,
            userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
            automaticSilentRenew: true,
            silent_redirect_uri: `${environment.client_root_url}assets/silent-redirect.html`
        };
        this._userManager = new UserManager(config);
        this._userManager.getUser().then(user => {
            if (user && !user.expired) {
                this._user = user;
                //this.loadSecurityContext();
            }
        });
        this._userManager.events.addUserLoaded(args => {
            this._userManager.getUser().then(user => {
                this._user = user;
                //this.loadSecurityContext();
            });
        });
    }


    login(): Promise<any> {
        return this._userManager.signinRedirect();
    }
}
```

**Environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    authority: 'https://localhost:44305/',
      client_id: 'mero-rental-angular-client',
      response_type: 'id_token token',
      scope: 'openid mero-rental-client-api profile',
      client_root_url: 'http://localhost:4200/'
}
```

Server side Code.
**CustomProfileService.cs**

```
public class CustomProfileService : IProfileService
    {
        private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUserViewModel> _claimsFactory;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUserViewModel> _userManager;

        public CustomProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUserViewModel> userManager, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUserViewModel> claimsFactory)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
        }

        public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
            var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);

            var claims = principal.Claims.ToList();

            if (user.Email == "admin@identity.localhost")
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
            }
            context.IssuedClaims = claims;
        }

        public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
        {
            var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
            context.IsActive = user != null;
        }
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

```
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUserViewModel, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, CustomProfileService>();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(GetClients())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUserViewModel>()
            .AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>();
        builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCors(builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
```

**config class**

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
        {
            return new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource( ConstantValue.ClientDashApi, ConstantValue.ClientApi)
            };
        }


        public IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            var client = new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                     ClientId = ConstantValue.ClientId,
                    ClientName = ConstantValue.ClientName,
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    RedirectUris =           { string.Format("{0}/{1}", Configuration["IdentityServerUrls:ClientUrl"], "assets/oidc-login-redirect.html"), string.Format("{0}/{1}", Configuration["IdentityServerUrls:ClientUrl"], "assets/silent-redirect.html") },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { string.Format("{0}?{1}", Configuration["IdentityServerUrls:ClientUrl"] , "postLogout=true") },
                    AllowedCorsOrigins =     { Configuration["IdentityServerUrls: ClientUrl"] },

                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        ConstantValue.ClientDashApi
                    },
                    IdentityTokenLifetime=120,
                    AccessTokenLifetime=120

                },
            };
            return client;
        }

        public IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
        {
            return new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile()
            };
        }
    }
```

**Constant Value**

```
public static class ConstantValue
    {
        public const string ClientId = "mero-rental-angular-client";
        public const string ClientName = "mero-rental";
        public const string ClientDashApi = "mero-rental-client-api";
        public const string ClientApi = "Mero Rental Client API";

    }
```

**Appsetting.json**

```
"IdentityServerUrls": {
    "Authority": "https://localhost:5002/",
    "ClientUrl": "http://localhost:4200"
  }
```

I, am able to login successfully and able to see the jwt token with bearer code. But on the browser keep getting an error as shown below.

[image: more details image]

When decode the image in JWT.IO website found the below information.
[image: jwt info]

[image: addede more details]

Done some research - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1194
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1249
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1608
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/userinfo.html

[image: added debug details]

**Errors**

```
GET https://localhost:44305/connect/userinfo net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
oidc-login-redirect.html:13 Error: Network Error
    at XMLHttpRequest.s.onerror (oidc-client.min.js:3)
mgr.signinRedirectCallback.then.error @ oidc-login-redirect.html:13
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ oidc-login-redirect.html:7
```

Comment: Is there any error if you send the request to `/connect/userinfo` with `Bearer <access_token>`? Try send this request from postman. In addition, you may need to place `app.UseMvc` after `app.UseIdentityServer(); app.UseAuthentication();`

Comment: Since my angular application was running on http and identity server and web api were running on https. Since it a cors issues but for the temporary purpose I used https for all.

Comment: Do you mean it works with https? What do you want to share us with this comment?

Comment: Yes it work on https. I added the cors in identity server. Shouldn't it work ?

Comment: Not sure what your current issue is.

Comment: I am seeing similar (net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE) intermittent errors in chrome console. I think it may have to do with Asp Net Core 2.2. Not really sure, but check this SO question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/53906866/4794396.

Comment: I got the exact same scenario, and exact same problem. Any solution to this so far? It always fails during the `.signinRedirectCallback()` method, specifically during the claims validation when it calls the `userinfo` endpoint with the oidc-client internal service `JsonService`. It fails as shown by OP, only from browser. When I try to reproduce exact same request from Postman, it succeeds without any issue.

Comment: Found an answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53965732/1658737
Long story short: either use the workaround shown there or just upgrade to SDK ASP.NET Core 2.2.1.