# net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE error after post request with Angular 7

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, angular7

I am working on small web application and I am using angular 7 and asp.net core web api as a back end. I am trying to make http post request with angular. My service returns string (token) and when I receive it, I want to show it in alert box.

I have tested my service with `Postman` and everything works as expected.

From the browser my request is successfully mapped to the controller's action method. I have set breakpoint in this method body and it successfully returns token without any problem.

But httpclient returns error:

`[object Object]`

And in the browser console I see this:

`POST https://localhost:44385/api/auth net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`

I have two methods (for `POST` and for `GET)` in a service class injected into component. They look like these:

```
logIn(username: string, password: string) {

    const encodedCredentials = btoa(username + ':' + password);

    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Authorization": "Basic " + encodedCredentials,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
        }),
        responseType: 'text' as 'text'
    };

    this.http.post(this.urlBase + 'auth', null , httpOptions)
    .subscribe(result => {
        alert(result);
    }, error => {
        alert(error); // [object Object]
    });
}

get(){
    return this.http.get(this.urlBase + 'auth', {responseType: 'text'});
}
```

What can be problem?

**Update:**

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "https://localhost:44385/api/auth", __zone_symbol__loadfalse: null, __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__xhrListener: ƒ, …}
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
lengthComputable: false
loaded: 0
path: []
returnValue: true
srcElement: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "https://localhost:44385/api/auth", __zone_symbol__loadfalse: null, __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__xhrListener: ƒ, …}
target: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "https://localhost:44385/api/auth", __zone_symbol__loadfalse: null, __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__xhrListener: ƒ, …}
timeStamp: 80234.59999999614
total: 0
type: "error"
__proto__: ProgressEvent
headers: HttpHeaders
headers: Map(0) {}
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
__proto__: Object
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: null
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

**Update 2:**

Request with Postman:

[image]

---

[image]

**Update 3:** trying to get token several times showed that sometimes post request is successfull and sometimes not...

[image]

Comment: Put a breakpoint or use console.log to see the contents of the error object.

Comment: @SachinGupta, I updated my question.

Comment: *(unknown url)?*

Comment: How you are calling with the PostMan?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, I updated my question.

Comment: Try header as:`const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: Check also this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900264/angular6-read-response-body-of-text-plain

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, same happens, I will check this question..

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900264/angular6-read-response-body-of-text-plain) it doesn't help too..

Comment: I checked without async task and working fine for me!

Comment: Try without declaring any content type in headers!

Comment: I check without async task too, but same happens.. I tried also without any content type in headers...

Comment: I faces with the exact same problem here ! However I tried with other API and it's working :( ...

Comment: I also tried to downgrade Angular, but same problem :( ...

Comment: @ChristopheGigax, it means problem is in communication between them?

Comment: @publicpublic not sure, Web API is correct ! We can request it with Postman ... Maybe Angular is unable to process something into the response. but I can't figure out what's the problem ...

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I made a test with [CoreAngular](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsyeWQ2z51P3hxaGIVJiQ3VAdZBi), but I fail to reproduce your issue with `https://localhost:44340/fetch-data`.

Comment: @TaoZhou, I have created angular client app outside of Web API project. I only have added cors configuration in API, nothing else.. I will put code on github as soon as I can..

Comment: @TaoZhou, this is code https://github.com/publicpublic70/problem

Comment: I change the request path to your uploaded project, but fail to reproduce your issue. Could you share us the complete project with angular client? What is installed .net core sdk? My is `3.0.100-preview-009765`

Comment: I added client application in this repo. I think I found problem as shown in `README.md`. I am using .NET core 2.2

Comment: I have been experiencing the same problem with similar setup (Angular 7 & Asp Net Core 2.2). But Christophe's answer seems sensinble. I tried creating demo app, and in that, with core 2.1 everything worked fine, but starts failing intermittently if I use 2.2. Please update us in case you find the solution. I will also do the same if I manage to find the solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core 2.2, we released a new Server which runs inside IIS for Windows scenarios. The issue you are running into looks like: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4398.

When sending the XMLHttpRequest, there is a preflight OPTIONS request which returns a status code of 204. This was incorrectly handled by the IIS server, returning an invalid response to the client.

In your ASP.NET Core application, can you please try the workaround for now:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
  await next();
  if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 204)
  {
    ctx.Response.ContentLength = 0;
  }
});
```

in the beginning of `Configure` method.

This will also be fixed in the next patch release of ASP.NET Core. I will follow up when the patch is released.

Edit:
The latest release (2.2.1) should address this problem: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2. Please try and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: yes, yes, that's what it sounds like. Thanks for the GitHub source.

Comment: This was the issue for me. The workaround solved the problem, but for anyone else who runs into this, it did need to be listed first in the startup configure - order matters!

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, @Capo. I've been freaking out all morning with this workaround at the end of the pipeline :(

Comment: @CesarD no problem! FYI it appears this has been fixed as of this morning https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4398

Comment: Yes I got that a few minutes after I made this work. Version 2.2.1 of SDK already integrates the fix for this issue. Thanks!!

Comment: This got me out of a jam.  Fix worked. But funny it only presented, for me, with one project.  Others were working fine...

Comment: I'm getting this with .NET Framework 4.6 as well and my ASP.NET packages are the latest version. Is there any reason this should be happening with Framework?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out where the problem is located. It's on the server side. Did you use ASP.NET Core 2.2 ? After downgrading to 2.1, it's finally working !

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

But I can't understand why. The only thing that changed is in one header, the **Server** header. It changed from **Microsoft-IIS/10.0** (2.2) to **Kestrel** (2.1)

Comment: Yes you are right. This is connected to ASP.NET Core 2.2. ASP.NET Core 2.1 works well, I think there will be solution other than downgrading to 2.1

Comment: I hope so ^^ But can't understand why :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem behind the dotnet core version. If the dotnet core 2.2.101 then it's have the problem. I have changes latest version i.e. 2.2.102 then it's resolving the issue. Similarly If you get the oldest version of dotnet core<2.2.101 then it's resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

hello the same thing happened to me and it was because I was pointing to a wrong url

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).